# recursively finding value of a String from a map

Tags: java, expression

I have a hashmap containing Key and Value `<String, String>`.

i.e. mapValue:

```
mapValue.put("A","B-7");
mapValue.put("B","START+18");
mapValue.put("C","A+25");
```

Now I want to evaluate expression for `'C'`. So for `C`, the expression would be 
replaced by `(((START+18)-7)+25)`.

So if anymethod, I will pass the string `C`, it should return string 
`"(((START+18)-7)+25)"` and also I want to evaluate it as per the priority.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you need to parse the map values and then evaluate the non-terminals. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Who generates all these upvotes?

Comment: It's not that difficult recursion function actually. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Doing this you should be careful to not replace `A` in `START`

Comment: Instead of parsing the expression , modify  the map to a terminal expression ,i.e A should represent START+11, etc. Please share your attempts.

Comment: Better to use some special symbol before variables, like `"$B-7"`, `"$A+25"` but `"START+18"`

Comment: Where do you get the values from? Do you receive those values from a database? Or from user input? I would recommend to rethink your data storage - parsing strings can get quite slow. Also I would try to prevent recursion here to avoid stackoverflow-exceptions (try using a loop) - unless there is a limited depth of recursion.

Comment: @reto I am not able to recurse it and make it a simple expression.

Comment: @slartidan It is not DB. the map is dynamically generated.

Comment: Hint: `mapValue.get("non_existing_key")` is `null` - consider it as a stop condition for the recursion.

Comment: @MarounMaroun the key will never go with non_existing_key or null.

Comment: Is your expression always in a `<other key>+-<number literal>` form?

Comment: @Ilya I would prefer `"${B}-7"` before `"$B-7"`. This will help in cases, where a variablename is dependent on another variable (i.e. `"${B${A}}"` is a variable whose name consists out of `B` and the value of `A`)

Comment: @Kumar in what form is the data, that is used to generate the map? Is the data entered by a user? Or received over HTTP? Or stored as Java-Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally logic of such function (assuming, you know possible operations and syntax is strict) may as follows:

```
public String eval(HashMap<String, String> mapValue, String variable) {
    //get expression to be evaluated
    String tmp = mapValue.get(variable); 
    // For each knwon operation
    for (String op : OPERATIONS) { 
        // split expression in operators in Array
        String[] vars = tmp.split("\\" + op); 
        // for each Element of splitted expr. Array
        for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) { 
            //Check if Element is a valid key in HashMap
            if (mapValue.containsKey(vars[i])) { 
                //if it is replace element with result of iteration
                vars[i] = eval(mapValue, vars[i]); // DO ITERATION
            }
            //if Element is not a valid key in has do nothing
        }
        //Join splitted string with proper operator
        tmp = join(vars, op);
    }
    //return in parenthesis
    return "(" + tmp + ")";
}
```

The result of 'eval(mapValue,"C")' would be:

```
(((START+18)-7)+25)
```

Some short join function may be implemented as follows:

```
public String join(String[] arr, String d) {
    String result = arr[0];
    int i = 1;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        result += d + arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

All code provided above is more to illustrate logic, as some exception handling, better operations with string etc should be used.

Hope it helps

Cheers!

Comment: HOw to evaulate this expression to get  the final result.?

Comment: I found the solution to evaluate the expression. However, will it work if "A+B-26" case?

Comment: No it will not. As a part of strict syntax i also meant that only _one_ operation and _two_ operands are possible in one statement, something like in an assembly language. Othervise the problem for case containing two different operatoins will occure due to way of splitting statement in parts. Overcome this limitation, you can for example split the statement by all known operations _at once_. This will lead to question: how to figure out which operand caused splitting on "join" operation.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments I would not recommend recursion - it can lead to stackoverflow-Exceptions, if the recursion gets too deep.

Also I would recommend not to use String equations. Strings are slow to parse and can lead to unexpected results (as mentioned by @rtruszk "START" contains variable "A").

I created an example as my recommendation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class X {

    static interface Expression {

    }

    static class Combination implements Expression {
        Expression[] values;

        public Combination(Expression... values) {
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "?";
        }
    }

    static class Reference implements Expression {
        private String reference;

        public Reference(String reference) {
            this.reference = reference;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return reference;
        }
    }

    static class Number implements Expression {
        private int value;

        public Number(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ""+value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Expression> mapValue = new HashMap<>();

        mapValue.put("START", new Number(42));
        String x = "C";

        mapValue.put("A", new Combination(    new Reference("B"), new Number(-7)));
        mapValue.put("B", new Combination(new Reference("START"), new Number(+18)));
        mapValue.put("C", new Combination(    new Reference("A"), new Number(+25)));

        int result = 0;
        ArrayList<Expression> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        parts.add(mapValue.get(x));
        while (!parts.isEmpty()) {

            debuggingOutput(x, result, parts);

            Expression expression = parts.remove(0);
            if (expression instanceof Combination)
                parts.addAll(Arrays.asList(((Combination) expression).values));
            else if (expression instanceof Reference)
                parts.add(mapValue.get(((Reference) expression).reference));
            else if (expression instanceof Number)
                result += ((Number) expression).value;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static void debuggingOutput(String x, int result, ArrayList<Expression> parts) {
        System.out.print(x);
        System.out.print(" = ");
        System.out.print(result);
        for (Expression part : parts) {
            System.out.print(" + ");
            System.out.print(part);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not recommending reflection or recursion?

Comment: @rtruszk neither nor :) But thanks for the hint - I updated the text to "recursion"